# How to check whether the upload file is PDF in PHP

Tags: php, pdf, mime

For an upload file type checking , I have implemented:

```
$_FILES["file"]["type"][$i] == 'application/pdf'
```

however, this checking will not work on the case I changed the extension name.

So , after some research, I have tried

```
$finfo = new finfo();
$fileMimeType = $finfo->file($_FILES["file"]["name"][$i] );
```

OR:

```
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$fileMimeType = finfo_file($finfo,$_FILES["file"]["name"][$i])
```

however, $fileMimeType echo nothing.

How to fix the problem? thanks

Comment: you can use `file` shell command, or `fread` the first few bytes of the file then you can know the type.

Comment: would you mind provide an example for a upload file case? thanks

Comment: Why would you change the extension?

Comment: You may be interested in this post [Why am I getting mime-type of .csv file as “application/octet-stream”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12061030/why-am-i-getting-mime-type-of-csv-file-as-application-octet-stream)

Comment: @user782104 i have posted an answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is using:

```
$_FILES["my_file"]["name"]
```

as it only contains the name of the uploaded file. If you want to check the file before moving it using `move_uploaded_file` you can refer to the temp file using:

```
$_FILES["my_file"]["tmp_name"]
```

Answer (score 6):

Read the first 4 bytes of the file and check that they match `%PDF`.

```
$filename = "pdffile";
$handle = fopen($filename, "r");
$header = fread($handle, 4);
fclose($handle);
```

Check $header against `%PDF`

Comment: When you say check do you mean   in_array($header, "%PDF");  ?  Not sure how to do this with the %

Answer (score 1):

if you read the file using `fread` you need to have a dictionary of all the file header type definitions. If you want to use the `file` shell command

```
$out = exec("file 'R-intro.pdf' | cut -d: -f2 | cut -d, -f1");
if (trim($out) == "PDF document") {
   echo "1";
}
```

To further expand on how to replace the constant file name with a uploaded file refer below.

```
$out = exec("file '" . $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] . "' | cut -d: -f2 | cut -d, -f1");
```

Comment: Thanks for answering . As i am checking upload file , which should be a temp file ( $_FILES["file"]["name"][$i] ) , how can I check it using shell script ?

Comment: this is not a shell script, this is php script using a shell command, you need to replace the `R-intro.pdf` with the tmp file name