# if(in_array) mime check always returns FALSE

Tags: php, arrays, csv, if-statement

Variables:

```
$csvFile = $_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'];
$csvFile = $con->real_escape_string($csvFile);
$mimes = array('application/vnd.ms-excel','text/plain','text/csv','text/tsv','csv');
```

`if` statement:

```
if(in_array($csvFile, $mimes))
{
$file = fopen($csvFile, 'r');
$i = 0;
$row = 1; 
while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) 
{
if($row == 1){ $row++;  continue; }
$data_array[$i] = $line[0];
$data_array[$i] = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, trim($data_array[$i]));
$encrypted_numbers[$i] = encryption::encrypt($data_array[$i]);
$encrypted_numbers[$i] .= mysqli_real_escape_string($con, trim($line[1]));
$i++;
}
fclose($file);
} 
else 
{
die("Sorry, file type not allowed");
};
```

I've been trying stuff for 30 min, anyone know why I always get false even if the file is named csv.csv?

Comment: what does var_dump($csvFile) before the in_array call give you ?

Comment: most likely $csvFile will give you the actual file name and not the mime type for that file which is what you are trying to do with in_array.

Comment: @Maximus2012 string(26) "D:\\xampp\\tmp\\phpAC6.tmp"

Comment: @user2671532 this will always result in in_array returning false when you try to match it with $mimes.

Comment: @Maximus2012 I realize that, and I tried having csvFile without a temp name and then imploding it, still got false even though var_dump gave me "csv.csv" name

Comment: you need to get the mime type for the file. See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134833/how-do-i-find-the-mime-type-of-a-file-with-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'];
```

you should be looking in 'type' not 'tmp_name'

```
$_FILES['uploadfile']['type'];
```

However, there is an SO [discussion here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12061030/why-am-i-getting-mime-type-of-csv-file-as-application-octet-stream) about why a csv file can have the `application/octet-stream` mime-type. It suggests that you need to verify the file-type yourself, and not rely on `['type']`. The best way would be to use [fgetcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) to try to parse it as csv. If this fails then assume it is not a csv.

Comment: exact same thing happens

Comment: Print or echo the ['type'] to see what it is.

Comment: application/octet-stream

Comment: That indicates it is a binary file. Is it really a csv? Open it in Notepad++ or similar. The filename isn't something.csv.csv or possibly csv.csv.txt is it?

Comment: The name is "csv.csv", it's made in OpenOffice.org Calc and saved as "CSV file", under the file it says "CSV file"

Comment: You are welcome. csv's are not as easy to discover as, for example, an image.