# PHP file upload on server changed mime-type to application/octet-stream

Tags: php, file-upload, wamp, mime-types, nette

I have a file upload and when I test it on localhost all mime-types are ok.
(txt, pdf, doc, docx, xls, xlsx)

When I test the same files on the server it changes all mime-types to application/octet-stream.

Is there any setting in PHP.ini or anywhere else to set it?

Server is using WAMP.

PHP Framework Nette

Comment: Please check thislink for help and explanation:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12061030/why-am-i-getting-mime-type-of-csv-file-as-application-octet-stream

Comment: But why does it behave different on server and on localhost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that there wasn't fileinfo extension in PHP on the server.
After activating all works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The answer as someone mentioned above is the way the RFC spec works.  Check out [Why am I getting mime-type of .csv file as "application/octet-stream"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12061030/why-am-i-getting-mime-type-of-csv-file-as-application-octet-stream) for more info.