# LARAVEL: The file must be a file of type: mpga

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation

Im trying to upload an audio/mp3 document (15mb), that generates the following error "The file must be a file of type: mpga". When I upload other document audio/mp3 (7mb), the error does not appear.

**In the validation:**

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
                    'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
                    'file' => 'required|mimes:mpga'
                ]);
```

**in php.ini**

```
upload_max_filesize=25M
max_file_uploads=25
post_max_size=25M
```

More info about two files:

**The first Document** (error)

```
Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile {#414
  -test: false
  -originalName: "bondad (1).mp3"
  -mimeType: "audio/mp3"
  -size: 4734618
  -error: 0
  #hashName: null
  path: "C:\xampp\tmp"
  filename: "php208F.tmp"
  basename: "php208F.tmp"
  pathname: "C:\xampp\tmp\php208F.tmp"
  extension: "tmp"
  realPath: "C:\xampp\tmp\php208F.tmp"
  aTime: 2017-12-19 13:53:30
  mTime: 2017-12-19 13:53:30
  cTime: 2017-12-19 13:53:30
  inode: 0
  size: 4734618
  perms: 0100666
  owner: 0
  group: 0
  type: "file"
  writable: true
  readable: true
  executable: false
  file: true
  dir: false
  link: false
  linkTarget: "C:\xampp\tmp\php208F.tmp"
}
```

The second document (Ok)

```
-test: false
  -originalName: "10 minutos de meditacion respirando.mp3"
  -mimeType: "audio/mp3"
  -size: 14418620
  -error: 0
  #hashName: null
  path: "C:\xampp\tmp"
  filename: "phpBFBB.tmp"
  basename: "phpBFBB.tmp"
  pathname: "C:\xampp\tmp\phpBFBB.tmp"
  extension: "tmp"
  realPath: "C:\xampp\tmp\phpBFBB.tmp"
  aTime: 2017-12-19 13:55:16
  mTime: 2017-12-19 13:55:16
  cTime: 2017-12-19 13:55:16
  inode: 0
  size: 14418620
  perms: 0100666
  owner: 0
  group: 0
  type: "file"
  writable: true
  readable: true
  executable: false
  file: true
  dir: false
  link: false
  linkTarget: "C:\xampp\tmp\phpBFBB.tmp"
```

Comment: i've found the answer in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39594854/why-does-laravels-getmimetype-method-identify-a-file-as-application-octet-st

Answer (score 1):

It might depend on what is exactly in mp3 file. I think better solution might be using:

```
mimes:mp3
```

instead of:

```
mimes:mpga
```

or you can combine multiple mimes like so:

```
mimes:mpga,mp3
```

Comment: Or better yet, `mimes:mp3,mpga`

Comment: I've discover that the mimetype is: "application/octet-stream", How i cant validate this type?

Comment: @AngelPrieto There is also `mimetypes` validation rule, so you can use it instead for example like this: 'mimetypes:application/octet-stream,audio/mpeg`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [mimetypes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-mimetypes) validation rule to match mime types, here is an example:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
    'file' => 'required|mimetypes:audio/mp3,application/octet-stream'
]);
```

Hope this hepls