# How do I access file mimeType in Laravel 5.8?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I had this

`$file      = array('file' => Input::file('file'));`

and

`dd($file);` return

[image]

How do I access file mimeType via the **Laravel** way ?

Comment: try `$file->getClientMimeType()` or `$file->getMimeType()` [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39594854/why-does-laravels-getmimetype-method-identify-a-file-as-application-octet-st)

Comment: `Call to a member function getMimeType() on array`

Comment: Someone that downvote my post, please explain why !, sO i can learn not to do it again.

Comment: update `$file = array('file' => Input::file('file'));` to `$file  = Input::file('file');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use one of this functions:

- `$file['file']->getClientMimeType();`

  > The client mime type is extracted from the request from which the file was uploaded, so it should not be considered as a safe value.
  >   For a trusted mime type, use `getMimeType()` instead (which guesses the mime type based on the file content).
- `$file['file']->getMimeType();`

  > The mime type is guessed using a `MimeTypeGuesserInterface` instance, which uses `finfo_file()` then the "file" system binary, depending on which of those are available.

Answer (score 1):

You can the mime type of the file retrieve it like this:

```php
$file['file']->getMimeType();
```

Comment: I tried `dd($file[0]->getMimeType());` I got `Undefined offset: 0`

Comment: `dd($file['file']->getMimeType());`

Comment: @cyber8200 Oops it should be `'file'` like @Rimble said.