# Laravel evaluates JPEG as of mime-type application/octet-stream but php and ubuntu correctly state image/jpeg

Tags: php, laravel, mime-types, laravel-7

In a Laravel 7 application I am uploading images. In my last batch I uploaded roughly 600 jpegs and 80 of these jpegs failed to be uploaded becaus of a Laravel validation error. The other jpegs were uploaded successful.

I checked all these 80 jpegs manually via Ubuntu command line tool `file` and also via php-interactive-mode `finfo`. Both tell that the mime-type is `image/jpeg`.

But my code in Laravel

```
    $this->validate($request, [
        'file'  => 'required',
        'file'  => 'file',
        'file'  => 'mime-types:image/jpeg'
    ]);
```

returns `message: "The given data was invalid.", errors: {file: ["validation.mime_types"]}}` beause the mime-type was evaluated to be `application/octet-stream` from Laravel.

I then thought okay, Laravel might do some special coding. Therefore I checked the source-code of Laravel at [FileinfoMimeTypeGuesser.php](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/d093475ce546dfef738139cd10f90fb718bc4c68/src/Symfony/Component/Mime/FileinfoMimeTypeGuesser.php#L47) and at [FileBinaryMimeTypeGuesser.php](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/d093475ce546dfef738139cd10f90fb718bc4c68/src/Symfony/Component/Mime/FileBinaryMimeTypeGuesser.php#L64). But Laravel obviously only either uses `file -b --mime -- %s` or `new \finfo(\FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE, $this->magicFile)`; so nothing special at all.

And both code-options result in (as written before) `image/jpeg` when I use `file` on the Ubuntu command line or `finfo` in an interactive-mode php session for any of the above mentioned 80 jpegs which Laravel rejected.

Can anyone help me on this? How is Laravel determining the mime-type? Maybe there is a magic database in Laravel which I need to update?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try this question [Why does Laravel's getMimeType() method identify a file as “application/octet-stream” when the file has the type attribute of “audio/mpeg”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39594854/why-does-laravels-getmimetype-method-identify-a-file-as-application-octet-st)

Comment: Hi @bhucho. I did read the question you are referring to and the answers. They basically acknowledge that Laravel is wrong and suggest to use other functions. Certainly I could do that, but this is not really elegant. I try to understand where Laravel's mistake is in the Laravel source-code. Therefore please help me to identify this in Laravel source-code. Or maybe it might also be the magic-database which needs to be updated. T