# Mime type was changed and File not detected

Tags: laravel

I host a laravel project/app in Infinity free. My web application contains a file uploading but when I try to upload in a live server it doesnt work. Here is the code for managing upload:

```
public function submitItem(Request $request)
{
    // dd($request->file('item_image'));
    DB::beginTransaction();
    try {
        $item = new Item();

        $item->item_name = $request->item_name;
        $item->item_qty = $request->item_quantity;
        $item->single_price = $request->single_price;
        $item->bundle_price = $request->bundle_price;
        $item->processor_id = $request->processor;
        $item->category_id = $request->category;
        $item->description = $request->description == null ? "" : $request->description;

        if($request->hasFile('item_image')){
            // $path = $request->file('item_image')->store('images');
            // $item->image_url = $path;

            // $file = $request->file('item_image')->getRealPath();
            // $image = file_get_contents($file);
            // $base64 = base64_encode($image);

            // $item->image_url = $base64;

            $uploadedFile = $request->file('item_image');
            $extension = $uploadedFile->getMimeType();
            $filename = pathinfo($uploadedFile->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_FILENAME);

            // Ensure the filename is unique to avoid overwriting existing files
            $filename = $filename . '_' . time();

            Storage::disk('public')->put('items/'.$filename.'.'.$extension, $uploadedFile);
            $item->image_url = $filename;
        }

        $item->save();

        DB::commit();
        Alert::success('Success', 'Item Added!');
        return redirect()->route('Items: ')->with('message', 'Item Added!');
        // return back();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        // echo $e;
        DB::rollBack();
        echo $e;
        // return redirect('/error');
    }


    // return $item;
}
```

when I try to die and dump in localhost is should appear like this which is ok:

Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile {#362 ▼ // app\Http\Controllers\ItemController.php:92
-test: false
-originalName: "Galax  RTX 4060 1-Click OC 2X 8GB GDDR6.jpg"
-mimeType: "image/jpeg"
-error: 0
#hashName: null
path: "C:\Users\marjon\AppData\Local\Temp"
filename: "php3DD8.tmp"
basename: "php3DD8.tmp"
pathname: "C:\Users\marjon\AppData\Local\Temp\php3DD8.tmp"
extension: "tmp"
realPath: "C:\Users\marjon\AppData\Local\Temp\php3DD8.tmp"
aTime: 2023-11-23 09:47:59
mTime: 2023-11-23 09:47:59
cTime: 2023-11-23 09:47:59
inode: 17169973579535044
size: 16874
perms: 0100666
owner: 0
group: 0
type: "file"
writable: true
readable: true
executable: false
file: true
dir: false
link: false
linkTarget: "C:\Users\marjon\AppData\Local\Temp\php3DD8.tmp"
}

however this is in the live server:

Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile {#362 ▼ // app/Http/Controllers/ItemController.php:93
-test: false
-originalName: "GALAX GeForce RTX™ 4070 EX Gamer 1-Click OC 12GB GDDR6X 192-bit (PINK).jfif"
-mimeType: "application/octet-stream"
-error: 6
#hashName: null
path: ""
filename: ""
basename: ""
pathname: ""
extension: ""
realPath: "/home/vol2_8/infinityfree.com/if0_35473659/htdocs"
aTime: 1970-01-01 00:00:00
mTime: 1970-01-01 00:00:00
cTime: 1970-01-01 00:00:00
inode: false
size: false
perms: 00
owner: false
group: false
type: false
writable: false
readable: false
executable: false
file: false
dir: false
link: false
}

I try to changed some functions but it doesn't work. I try to move the code outside the if condition but error 500 status appeared.

Comment: I think this will help you understand the logic 
 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39594854/why-does-laravels-getmimetype-method-identify-a-file-as-application-octet-st

Answer (score 0):

The `getMimeType` method guesses the mime type based on the uploaded file content not by the file extension **For Security Reasons** which is the best way.

However, if you want to use the file extension instead you can use `getClientMimeType` method.

I recommend reading the [method's documentation](https://pkp.sfu.ca/ojs/doxygen/master/html/classSymfony_1_1Component_1_1HttpFoundation_1_1File_1_1UploadedFile.html#ab964fa86f67e89bc340a424fbaee654b) for more understanding.