# Laravel 5.4 UploadedFile::getMimeType returns incorrect mimetype

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I have a valid `.eps` file which I want to upload.
My validator looks like this:

```
        // $file is an instance of UploadedFile
        $validator = \Validator::make( [
            'file' => $file
        ], [
            'file' => 'required|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png,tiff,psd,ai,eps,pdf'
        ] );
\dd($validator->fails());
        if ($validator->fails() ){
            ...
        }
```

`$validator->fail()` evaluates to true at the moment, causing my script to not upload the file.
Because all other file extensions are working, I think this is because laravel doesn't understand the eps file type. Therefore I'd like to implement the eps mime types myself but I don't know how to do this.

The file I try to upload is named `2365 MD8300_PC_03.eps` and has `application/octet-stream` as mimetype.

Any ideas?

#### Update:

When I `dd` `$file`, it's output is this:

```
UploadedFile {#410 ▼
  -test: false
  -originalName: "2365 MD8300_PC_03.eps"
  -mimeType: "application/postscript"
  -size: 310578
  -error: 0
  #hashName: null
  path: "/private/var/tmp"
  filename: "phpy3tsMr"
  basename: "phpy3tsMr"
  pathname: "/private/var/tmp/phpy3tsMr"
  extension: ""
  realPath: "/private/var/tmp/phpy3tsMr"
  aTime: 2017-07-11 12:08:52
  mTime: 2017-07-11 12:08:50
  cTime: 2017-07-11 12:08:50
  inode: 21487530
  size: 310578
  perms: 0100600
  owner: 504
  group: 0
  type: "file"
  writable: true
  readable: true
  executable: false
  file: true
  dir: false
  link: false
}
```

So the actual mime type is correct, it's just that `$file->getMimeType()` returns an incorrect value of `application/octet-stream`.

Comment: what is the value of `$file` ?

Comment: @SagarGautam $file is an instance of `UploadedFile`

Comment: I think `application/octet-stream ` refers to binery file. Are you sure about mime type of `eps` file ?

Comment: take o look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12061030/why-am-i-getting-mime-type-of-csv-file-as-application-octet-stream) !!

Comment: try passing it like this 'file' => 'required|mimes:application/octet-stream' and check

Comment: Since, You know mime type is `application/postscript` so try with this rather than `eps`

Comment: @Exprator no, because in the http specification `If the media type remains unknown, the recipient SHOULD treat it as type "application/octet-stream"` so all ununknown types will pass validation !!

Comment: @Maraboc Is there a way to make this extension known to it's no long application/octet-stream